# Android Studio: Building to multiple targets

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, wear-os

I'm developing apps for Android Wear and Android Phone devices.  Both apps are in a common project in Android Studio.  In fact this application uses three wear devices that work together with a single phone.  So when I recompile for app testing, I need to build and install the apps on one phone AND three wear devices every time.  Is there a way to automatically build and install to all four of these devices with one command?  I imagine that a script could be run from the terminal in Android Studio, but I'm not sure where to start.  Thanks.

Comment: "I imagine that a script could be run" -- Isn't that what Gradle already does?

Comment: Well, I don't speak Gradle and I've never been clear where Android Studio (AS) ends and Gradle begins.  Does the script need to instruct Android Studio to begin the build?  Or does Gradle handle the whole build process?  If gradle handles the build, who handles the installation to the devices?  Gradle or AS?

Comment: Android Studio is simply an IDE where code is written. Gradle is the build script (with parallels to Maven & Ant). I would assume you can define a custom [Gradle task](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/tutorial_using_tasks.html) to execute the install processes for each of the wear modules and app. I'm not sure about specifying particular devices

Comment: Does anyone know the full gradle command executed by Android Studio?  It looks like the 'build.gradle' scripts are broken up into a project file and individual module files.

Comment: Well, without digging into any source code, you can see which tasks are immediately available (via `./gradlew tasks` from the project). Android Studio simply delegates to Gradle, so installing a `release` version of the app would run `gradlew installRelease`, which compiles, and assembles the app before running an `adb` command to install the generated APK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the recommendations above from cricket_007, I started digging around Android Studio to see if it would report the commands for installation.  I found the commands, put them in a shell script file and am now able to install the apk to four wear devices at once. 
So first, in Android Studio, I go to: Build | Build APK.  The generates the wear apk file.  Then I execute a shell script with the following commands:

```
echo "Installing 422E..."
adb -s G6NZCJ00401422E push /Users/fred/abcdec/apps/myWearApp/wear/build/outputs/apk/wear-debug.apk /data/local/tmp/com.xyz.myWearApp
adb -s G6NZCJ00401422E shell pm install -r "/data/local/tmp/com.xyz.myWearApp"
echo "Starting 422E..."
adb -s G6NZCJ00401422E shell am start -n "com.xyz.myWearApp/com.xyz.myWearApp.MainWearActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER


echo "Installing 6227..."
adb -s G6NZCJ004076227 push /Users/fred/abcdec/apps/myWearApp/wear/build/outputs/apk/wear-debug.apk /data/local/tmp/com.xyz.myWearApp
adb -s G6NZCJ004076227 shell pm install -r "/data/local/tmp/com.xyz.myWearApp"
echo "Starting 6227..."
adb -s G6NZCJ004076227 shell am start -n "com.xyz.myWearApp/com.xyz.myWearApp.MainWearActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER


echo "Installing 922a..."
adb -s G5NZCJ02746922A push /Users/fred/abcdec/apps/myWearApp/wear/build/outputs/apk/wear-debug.apk /data/local/tmp/com.xyz.myWearApp
adb -s G5NZCJ02746922A shell pm install -r "/data/local/tmp/com.xyz.myWearApp"
echo "Starting 922A..."
adb -s G5NZCJ02746922A shell am start -n "com.xyz.myWearApp/com.xyz.myWearApp.MainWearActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
echo "Done."

echo "Installing Moto…”
adb -s localhost:4444 push /Users/fred/abcdec/apps/myWearApp/wear/build/outputs/apk/wear-debug.apk /data/local/tmp/com.xyz.myWearApp
adb -s localhost:4444 shell pm install -r "/data/local/tmp/com.xyz.myWearApp"
echo "Starting Moto…”
adb -s localhost:4444 shell am start -n "com.xyz.myWearApp/com.xyz.myWearApp.MainWearActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
echo "Done."
```

Of course, this could be extended to install the mobile app as well.  I'm sure that I can find the gradle command to actually compile the .apk file as part of the script.  If I find that, I will also post it.